# iOS4 Create Background Timer

Tags: objective-c, ios4, localnotification, background-thread

I (Basically) need to create a background timer on iOS 4 that will allow me to execute some code when a specific amount of time has passed. I have read that you can accomplish this using some `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:
  toTarget:
  withObject:];` but how does that work in practice? How can I ensure that the thread remains in the background also. Local notifications will **NOT** work for me, as I need to execute code, not notify the user.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use those call to execute a method (selector) of an object (toTarget) with some parameter (withObject) in a new thread (detachNewThred).

Now if you want to execute a delayed task may be the best approach is `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` and the if you want to run the task on background call the `detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject:`

Comment: the `beast` approach :) Ok, so if I make a thread with `detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject:` will it stay in background?

Comment: jajaja, sorry about the "beast" approach =/ Yes it's will execute in parallel with the main thread, take a look to the `performSelector` methods in NSObject for the full list of possibilities.

Comment: Awesome man, thanks so much, i had been pulling my hair out! :)

Answer (score 20):

You can also do this using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). This way you can use blocks to keep your code in one place, and be sure you're calling the main thread again if you need to update your UI after you've finished background processing. Here's a basic example:

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

…

NSTimeInterval delay_in_seconds = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay_in_seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

UIImageView *imageView = tableViewCell.imageView;

// ensure the app stays awake long enough to complete the task when switching apps
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:{}];

dispatch_after(delay, queue, ^{
    // perform your background tasks here. It's a block, so variables available in the calling method can be referenced here.        
    UIImage *image = [self drawComplicatedImage];        
    // now dispatch a new block on the main thread, to update our UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
      imageView.image = image;
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskIdentifier];
    });
});
```

Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Blocks reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758

Background Task reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:

Comment: But this dispatch_after does not work in background. To check the same put the code in applicationDidEnterBackground: method and see whether your block is called or not.

Comment: Very good advice this background task. I'll try to remember it more often.

Answer (score 0):

Are these suggested methods only applicable if the application is enabled for background execution (using UIBackgroundMode) in the first place?

I presume if an application cannot legitimately claim to be a voip/music/location aware app then if it implements what is described here it will not execute when the time interval expires?

Comment: No, that is not correct, however, the chances of the app still running are slim, depending upon the time you set. When you have a voip / music / location app, the OS generally tries to keep it running no matter what, and not stop the process to free up resources.