# NSTimer Keep counting after app is closed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

I have a timer that have to count up to 8 hours (28800 second)
after that it should be released

im wondering how to keep the timer running at the background and/or when application is closed?

this is the NSTimer :

```
stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

and this is my condition :

```
 counter++;

if (counter >= 28800) {
    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    counter =0;

    timeLabel.text = @"Time Out";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer in this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154332/ios4-create-background-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - once your app is closed then it's not running anymore so the timer won't be running either.

Take a look at [local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 2):

When application goes in background, In **–(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:** application delegate method **add current counter value and current time in nsuserdefault**.

Now when application becomes active before that **–(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:** will called so in that method get total seconds application was in background ie **(current time of application) - (time when application went background which is stored in nsuserdefault) calculate in seconds**

so add this also in –(void)applicationWillEnterForeground :

```
 if((seconds calculated) > (28800 - (current counter value stored in nsuserdefault)))
 {
    // stop timer as it has gone beyond eight hours
 } 
 else
 {
  // continue task
 }
```

Comment: ok , but there will be a time difference between the time i went to background and time i got back

Comment: You understood the logic i described, if not ask it any query