# Xcode - Keep NSTimer running after closing application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstimer

Is there anyway to keep a timer running after the application is terminated (not in background). I want to do this so a local notification is triggered once the timer reaches 0.

Can UserDefaults be used to achieve this?

Comment: what kind of app is this?  iOS or Macintosh?  In general, NSTimers are killed off when the app quits.

Comment: have you tried using [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]];

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimer Keep counting after app is closed in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869835/nstimer-keep-counting-after-app-is-closed-in-iphone)

Comment: It is an IOS application. An no I haven't Ankit I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimer` cannot run infinitely in background. `NSTimer` is paused when your application enters background.

You have to use `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification` to achieve it.

```
UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
alarm.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
[app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
```

Comment: upvoting & accepting it as answer are equivalent ways of express gratitude :) - please consider do so if it did really help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you are talking about iOS, have a look at this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSTimer is not what you looking for, since it's only working at the runtime of your App. UILocalNotification let you create a notification (including scheduling it for s specific time) handled independently by the system.

Comment: While redirecting to a link is appreciated, Please consider giving your point to view/solution to the issue.